# How to create a "Drop-Up-Menu"?

Tags: ios, xcode, drop-down-menu, uipickerview

I want to create a drop up menu like this.

[image]

But I have no clue what it is called, so I can't look for it.

And by the way, are there others methods to create such a "more option"-menu? I know there is the UIPickerView, but if i have only 2 or 3 buttons to choose from it is fairly unnecessary to implement a whole pickview.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[David Wong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104551/david-wong) is right, you always can use UIActionSheet for iOS 7 style drop menu, but if you want to use some cool custom controllers here's the list:

Drop menus

- [REMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/REMenu)
- [LBActionSheet](https://github.com/larcus94/LBActionSheet)
- [NIDropDown](https://github.com/BijeshNair/NIDropDown)
- [LHDropDownControl](https://github.com/sirenum/LHDropDownControl)
- [kxmenu](https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmenu)

Modal (cool ones)

- [KGModal](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal)
- [RNGridMenu](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNGridMenu)
- [KNSemiModalViewController](https://github.com/kentnguyen/KNSemiModalViewController)

But if you're just starting your journey of iOS development, you better stick with UIActionSheet.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh wow thanks! One question: If i use these (the custom ones) in apps which i like to put on the app store, will Apple confirm these or the UIActionSheet only?

Comment: Yeah, Apple review board will surely will confirm these custom elements to App Store, I'm using almost all of these in my apps that already in App Store.

Answer (score 0):

That's a [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Just adds buttons and use the various show methods to bring it up. Don't forget to set the delegate to handle which button gets pressed.